Augmenting a mesh
I am quite new to Blender and I wonder if the following is possible:
I leveraged Photogrammetry to create a 3d mesh with texture of my office plant:

However, now I want to augment my plant to have many of them, but in different compositions (later on randomly create a version of this plant). How can I approach this problem? Currently it is one fixed mesh, all leaves, branches etc. stick together. However, I want to organize them differently in the 3D model. What is the right way to do this?
(I already started to separate the mesh such that every leaf is a single object. However, it is extremely time consuming and then for rearranging the leaves it needs a lot of manual work as well - as e.g. the leaf does not stick to the branch for instance.)

Probably the best way would be to model it using your photoscanned plant as a reference.

Well, the simple answer is without creating a completely new object: since a 3D scan only gives you a single mesh with more or less complex/messy geometry, you have to do it the tedious manual way. For just slight variations you might not even have to separate it. Select some faces of a leaf, then with Proportional Editing enabled move, rotate or scale them to create some variation. The Proportional Editing should take care of a smooth transition between the edited and non-edited parts.
